# variable value is not changing after going through the function which changes the value?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

I want to change the value of the variable after going through the function but it's not changing, I check there is no solution given on internet for this, down there was the code and I was expecting it to change the value of `filterName` but it doesn't change, it works if I not use if statement but they are important for checking the condition. and one more thing that `text` parameter is important in the `showFilter` function this was my react code but I was getting problem in JavaScript so I am asking it as JavaScript question please help me.

```
let show = false;
let text = "Color";

  let filterName;
  let filterName =''; // I tried this way too but it doesn't work.
  const showFilter = (text) => {
    if (show === true) {
      show = false;
    } else {
      show = true;
      if (text == 'Color') {
        filterName = 'color'; // the value should change here
      } else if (text === 'Price') {
        filterName = 'price';
      } else if (text === 'Brand') {
        filterName = 'brand';
      } else if (text === 'All Filters') {
        filterName = 'All Filters';
      }
    }
  }


alert(filterName); // it should have to be 'color' but it's undefined.
```

Comment: You're never calling  `showFilter('…')` in your code.

Comment: thanks for the  answer i really forgot to call that 

Answer (score 0):

```js
let show = false;
let text = "Color";

let filterName;
const showFilter = (text) => {
    if (show === true) {
        show = false;
        return;
    }
    show = true;
    switch (text) {
        case 'Color':
            filterName = 'color'; // the value should change here
            break;
        case 'Price':
            filterName = 'price';
            break;
        case 'Brand':
            filterName = 'brand';
            break;
        case 'All filters':
            filterName = 'All filters';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
showFilter(text);

alert(filterName);
```

Your code works just fine. You just need to call your method before calling the alert.

Comment: My pleasure ! If it works, you can validate the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

First you declared `filterName` variable twice, other thing you should call your function `showFilter(..)`, Here the result:

```js
let show = false;
let text = "Color";

  let filterName  '';
  const showFilter = (text) => {
    if (show === true) {
      show = false;
    } else {
      show = true;
      if (text == 'Color') {
        filterName = 'color'; // the value should change here
      } else if (text === 'Price') {
        filterName = 'price';
      } else if (text === 'Brand') {
        filterName = 'brand';
      } else if (text === 'All Filters') {
        filterName = 'All Filters';
      }
    }
  }

showFilter(text);
alert(filterName); // It shows 'color'
```